# SetProviders Method is marked deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am Developing Firebase android application following tutorial of Udacity.

The setProviders method is marked deprecated by IDE, after going through documentation i was unable to find the solution. Is there any way out to solve the problem.
Here is the code:

```
    mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are signed in, Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
               startActivityForResult(
                       AuthUI.getInstance()
                                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                        .setProviders(
                                                AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                                AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER
                                                )
                                        .build(),
                                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: The documentation you're looking for is here : https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#sign-in-examples

Answer (score 24):

**UPDATE:** You can now use `setAvailableProviders()` instead of the deprecated `setProviders()`

**Usage Example:**

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()))
            .build(),
    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Source: [Firebase UI for Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#adding-providers)

Thanks @Alexey

**The solution below will work but has been deprecated:**

I'm also following the same tutorial and ended up here searching for the solution. I tried to find a solution myself and have found it. There are two overloaded method for **setProviders()**. The one with **setProviders(String... providers)** is deprecated. I used **setProviders(List < IdpConfig > idpConfigs)**. Below is the code:

First create a List instance of IdpConfig, do this where you create instance of FirebaseDatabase. In other words, do this outside of all methods and inside your class.

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;
```

Write this in your **onCreate()** :

```
providers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then replace your code with this:

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are signed in, Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build());
                providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build());
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
```

You're done!
Have a good day :)

Comment: AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder() is deprecated now too. Should use setAvailableProviders() method with proper builders in it like shown [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth#adding-providers)

Answer (score 4):

Just replace "setProvider" with "setAvailableProviders", it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `setAvailableProviders()` instead of `setProviders` like shown in the FirebaseUI example at the following link: 
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#sign-in-examples

Answer (score 1):

Instead Of this Line :

```
setProviders(
             AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
             AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
            .build()
```

In new Version of FirebaseAuth 11.4.2 use setAailableProviders instead of setProviders As Follow :

```
setAvailableProviders(
Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
              new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()))
              .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your emulator and build API level are the same and not emulating at a higher API level. The Google play services error was coming from this for me.

Check this in the build.gradle file;

example below is API Level 24

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
...}
```